# Custom Edit Text Pointer Position

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, android-edittext

Ok, so I'm a little new to Android. So I'm pretty much following some online tutorials to get myself involved with some development.

I'm a Computer Science Undergraduate so my knowledge on Java is pretty extensive. I'm just having some issues with XML as I haven't used it before.

I'm trying to create a LoginActivity with some simple Login Forms.

I need the pointer to be shifted right slightly so It's inside the box itself.

Here's my .xml file.

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.unibites.LoginActivity" >

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/signinBtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="159dp"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
    android:src="@drawable/signin_btn" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/userEt"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/signinBtn"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/signinBtn"
    android:layout_marginBottom="86dp"
    android:background="@drawable/text_field"
    android:ems="10" />
```

[Link to the Simulator Image, where the pointer is currently at.](http://gyazo.com/ba81a819f94de05e29e5b870be15b782)

Comment: did you tried `userEt.setSelection(position);` where the position is the index/offset where you want to set the cursor position

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what you added here

```
android:background="@drawable/text_field"
```

without this piece of xml property/attribute the activity runs perfectly fine ! :)

little more code or detail would have been more helpful...

**Edit** Unable to take the screen shot of the cursor (it bloody blinks ! :P )

**RELEVANT ANSWER**

First of all pointer is blinking where it should be...its the image which needs to be sorted out

your problem will be solved by using 9patch images in the Edit Text.

convert your image to 9patch using this [link](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html) and then use it in your view

For Further information this is the [Android Developers Link](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html).

P.S. i used it now it worked.

Comment: little more info would have been greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's an image for the background of the edit text box. I need the image to be there, and due to the image, the edit text aligns it to the most left position of the image.